# Stored Procedure - How to Ignore a Join when @packageType = 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to change the left join to inner join, but for me to do that,
I want the `PACKAGEDETAILS.MenuID = MENU.ID` join to happen only if the `@packageType = 2`, else I want my stored procedure to ignore the join

I am new to stored procedures and SQL, I tried using case when, but I failed, I tried if then, still didn't achieve what I wanted.

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
set @slot = 5;
set @numberofattendees = 100;
set @foodtype = 0;
set @packagetype = 1;

select * FROM PROPERTY 

 JOIN PACKAGEDETAILS  ON  PACKAGEDETAILS.ID =

 (SELECT
   PACKAGEDETAILS.ID
  FROM
   PACKAGEDETAILS
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    LEFT JOIN MENU ON PACKAGEDETAILS.MenuID = MENU.ID AND  -- i want this join to happen only if the @packageType = 2
      MENU.IsActive = 1 AND
      MENU.IsDeleted = 0 AND
      (MENU.FoodTypeID = 0 OR @FoodType = 0)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    JOIN PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY ON PACKAGEDETAILS.ID = PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.packagedetailsid
  WHERE

    PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.IsActive = 1 AND
    PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.IsDeleted = 0 
  ORDER BY
    PACKAGEDETAILS.CostPrice ASC LIMIT 1
 )
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Since there wont be any menu for packageType 1, I want my stored procedure to ignore the join if @packageType = 1 and only work when @packageType = 2.

Comment: You want the columns from `menu` to disappear from the result or is having them with `NULL`s OK?

Comment: Well this is just a sub query, I need to select the `package Id` with the lowest cost price based on the `menu type` they select, for `packageType 1` there are no `menu`, so i wont be selecting any column from the `menu` table @stickybit

Comment: Mhh, you're right, I've overlooked that. But then your question doesn't make sense to me. You don't use any column of `menu` in your subquery to project, filter or sort by. And a left join doesn't eliminate rows. I guess you should [edit] the question and add `CREATE TABLE` statements, `INSERT INTO` statements for sample data and the expected results with that sample data to make clear what you're after here.

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clear enough,
`PackageDetails` table has `menuId` which is `fkey'd` to the `Menu` Table, this is the connection i'm using to filter the `packageId` with lowest cost price(packageDetails Table) based on the `foodType` that an user selects .  @stickybit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pack 2 different queries into 1. In general, that is not a good idea in SQL, as it makes the query optimizer work much harder. You will be better off with either writing 2 separate procedures, or within the same procedure, write 2 separate queries and use IF conditional execution to decide which query to execute:

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
IF Packagetype = 2
select * FROM PROPERTY 
 JOIN PACKAGEDETAILS  ON  PACKAGEDETAILS.ID =
 (SELECT
   PACKAGEDETAILS.ID
  FROM
   PACKAGEDETAILS
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    LEFT JOIN MENU ON PACKAGEDETAILS.MenuID = MENU.ID AND  -- i want this join to happen only if the @packageType = 2
      MENU.IsActive = 1 AND
      MENU.IsDeleted = 0 AND
      (MENU.FoodTypeID = 0 OR @FoodType = 0)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    JOIN PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY ON PACKAGEDETAILS.ID = PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.packagedetailsid
  WHERE
    PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.IsActive = 1 AND
    PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.IsDeleted = 0 
  ORDER BY
    PACKAGEDETAILS.CostPrice ASC LIMIT 1
 )
ELSE
select * FROM PROPERTY 
 JOIN PACKAGEDETAILS  ON  PACKAGEDETAILS.ID =
 (SELECT
   PACKAGEDETAILS.ID
  FROM
   PACKAGEDETAILS
    JOIN PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY ON PACKAGEDETAILS.ID = PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.packagedetailsid
  WHERE
    PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.IsActive = 1 AND
    PACKAGEAPPLICABILITY.IsDeleted = 0 
  ORDER BY
    PACKAGEDETAILS.CostPrice ASC LIMIT 1
 )
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable and construct your query by setting the variable according to your conditions. When you create the query execute it with exec command.

[Here](https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2009/01/09/creating-dynamic-where-clauses-with-sql) is an example.